# "Hats off" to Yaakov!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

As we begin to take our "hats off" as Winter Bash 2021 comes to an end, I want to also take my "[hats off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_one%27s_hat_off_to#English)" to Yaakov for his absolutely ***amazing*** helpfulness, kindness and patience with us in the [Winter Bash 2021 Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132350/winter-bash-2021) throughout this recent holiday period (especially on December 30th and January 2nd). Many of us found his responses there in the last few days ***extremely*** helpful, and it seems that every bug that we found got fixed and hats were awarded "manually" when needed. Everything was so efficient and fair.

I want to also thank the ***entire team*** for what I think was one of the best winter/summer bashes so far. You're all amazing! At the beginning I found this year's hats to be way harder to earn than in Winter Bash 2020, but as the event progressed it became more and more fun, as earning hats this year felt a lot more special whenever it did happen! All around, I think a lot of us, especially in the WB21 chatroom had a blast! Thank you!

Comment: His constant support made the event more fun.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to everyone
for your participation
we had a real blast!

I appreciate
the kind words so very much
much love and peace out!

It would be remiss
not to give a shout out to
my super teammates:

[Slate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1037447/slate), [Charlotte](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1035082/charlotte), [David](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/516441/david-longworth),
[Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija), [Felippe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/423506/felippe-rangel), [Rosie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/943183/rosie),
[Anita](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/349251/anita-taylor), and more

It takes a village
to prep all the hats for you.
Shalom, and stay safe.

And to quote Bill S.
Preston, Esquire: “Be
Excellent to each other!”

Comment: So is it cat-i-ja or fel-ipp-e for the 3 syllable name?

Comment: @Tim "Ka-tya" and "Fill-ee-pee"

Comment: To be clear, Felippe != Philippe.  Just to make things fun.

Comment: @Philippe Is your name 2 syllables, like "fill-eep" in the French style? That's how I've always said it in my head.

Comment: Mine is french style... "Fil-eep".  :)